# How do I use this function in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

```
//tools.js
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomString;
}
exports.randomString = randomString();


//test.js
var tools = require('./tools');
console.log(tools.randomString());
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
[Function: randomString]
```

How do I actually make it spit out a random string?

Comment: Note: I want to keep it where the function stands by itself. (so I can copy and paste stuff into the tools.js file like normal)

Comment: You're really blasting through these Node questions! It's good. We need some more fundamental questions on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a different name for your result. one which isn't the same as your function's name.

the variable `randomstring` contains your accumulated result but you return `randomString` which is just off it by case and is the name of the function.

Comment: huh? Give more detailed. Don't understand

Comment: Emmerman: It's because of a mistake in the code above: the function name is "randomString" (note the uppercase S), the string is built in "randomstring" (note the lowercase S), yet the last statement of the function is "return randomString".  Thus, it is returning the function and not the random string.

Answer (score 4):

`exports.randomString = randomString;`

or

`exports.randomString = function() {....}`

Comment: First one doesn't work. (and I dont want to use the second one)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know node.js in detail. But

```
exports.randomString = randomString();
```

already calls the function and assigns the result to exports.randomString.

To assign the reference you should take away the braces.

Second Bug:

```
return randomString;
```

needs to be (watch the case)

```
return randomstring;
```

as this is the variable where you build and store your random string.

Answer (score 2):

Are yor sure that your accepted answer fully resolves your problem?

If you do

```
exports.randomString = randomString();
```

then you call the random string function **exactly once** and assign the result to exports.randomString.

Please check and call **multiple times**

```
console.log(tools.randomString());
```

For more advice please read my other answer above. Hope I could help.